# amend commit in Fossil

Tags: commit, fossil, git-amend

In Git, to change the most recent commit on the current branch
one uses the `--amend` option to `git-commit`.

What would be the closest operation in *Fossil*? Is there
a way to add a GPG signature to an unsigned commit (`git commit --amend -S`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fossil amend can also just update the commit message:

```
    fossil amend COMMIT_ID -m 'my new commit message'
```

or

```
    fossil amend COMMIT_ID -e # launch $EDITOR to revise message
```

(These add a control artifact with the new/revised message which Fossil will display instead of the original.)

It has other functions as well: https://fossil-scm.org/fossil/help?cmd=amend

One possible way to add a sign-off to a commit might be:

```
    fossil amend COMMIT_D --tag sign-off=my_name
```

You could add a PGP/GPG signature to unsigned commit by turning on the manifest setting, checking out that commit, generating the PGP/GPG signature, then

```
    fossil amend COMMIT_ID --tag signature=SIGNATURE
```

Of course, this is harder than if amend directly supported adding a signature.

Comment: Just a note: when I used `fossil amend -e abcd1234` to edit a commit message, I couldn't work out how to get that change in my local repo reflected in the remote. `commit` did nothing. But `fossil push --all` did the trick: then both local and remote repos had the same (amended) message. FWIW.

Answer (score 3):

There **is** a way to amend a commit in Fossil, just like in git.  In fact the mechanism is identical, but the process (and what data remains) is different.

Both tools will create a new commit (git doesn't amend the original any more than fossil does), the difference is only in what happens to the original commit.

In git, the old commit is left dangling until eventually **deleted** permanently (unless tagged).

In fossil, it is put on a hidden branch and **kept** permanently (but you can still view it if needed).

The process with `git amend` is: you make changes first, then update the repo database.  In fossil, the other way around - which can also be done in git, shown below.

fossil (step 1 from: https://fossil-scm.org/fossil/doc/trunk/www/shunning.wiki):

```
$ # 1.
$ fossil amend abcd1234 --branch oops --hide
$ fossil up trunk

$ # 2.
$ fossil revert -r abcd1234

$ # 3.
$ $EDITOR the.file
$ fossil commit -m 'my new msg with amended code'
```

git:

```
$ # 1.
$ git reset --hard HEAD^

$ # 2.
$ git checkout abcd1234 .

$ # 3.
$ $EDITOR the.file
$ git commit -am 'my new msg with amended code'
```

In step 2, git still knows about the old commit as it hasn't been gc'd yet - you can see it in the reflog.

`git amend` just takes a shortcut, but the operations on the data are the same.

Answer (score 2):

In fossil, there is no way to amend a commit. As documented in [“Deleting content from Fossil”](https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/shunning.wiki),

> Fossil is designed to keep all historical content forever.

However you can if needed rollback a commit and redo it with proper GPG signature.

Comment: Their stance makes sense to some extent but it complicates simple actions like improving the commit message or adding a signoff line. This is what I habitually use ``--amend`` for: polishing the metadata, not the commit content.

Comment: how can I rollback a commit?

Comment: @xeruf you can use `fossil revert`